# Issue when combining two lists of text

Tags: python

I'm trying to combine the output from the code below.

Essentially, I want to maintain the string length of `lst_a`, but include all of the text formatting from `lst_b` (e.g. spelling, capitalization, punctuation).

**A few things to note:**

- If a words appears both in `lst_a` and `lst_b`, I want to include it in `new_lst`.
- If a word appears in `lst_b` and does not appear in `lst_a`, I want
  it included it in `new_lst`.
- If a word appears in `lst_a` and not
  in `lst_b`, I do not want it included in in `new_lst`.

**Code to produce two separate lists(new_lst, and temp[words in lst_b not in lst_a]):**

```
lst_a = ['it is an', 'example of', 'an english simple sentence']
lst_b = ['It\'s', 'an', 'example', 'of', 'an', 'English', 'simple', 'sentence.']

#create a new_list of same length as lst_a
new_list = ['']*len(lst_a)

#split the words in lst_a so you can access each word separately
a = [_.split(' ') for _ in lst_a]

#check each word against lst_b and if it is present, form the new list
for i, l in enumerate(a):
    new_list[i] = ' '.join([j for j in l if j in lst_b])

#this section is the addition to find the missing color from lst_b
#convert all the colors in lst_a into single items so you can scan against lst_b
s = [j for i in a for j in i]
#remove any duplicate words from lst_a
#Easier to process the smaller list
s = list(dict.fromkeys(s))

#now create a list of all items that are in lst_b but not in lst_a
temp = [x for x in lst_b if x not in s]

#now add list temp to new_list to create the full list

#finally print the new list that contains only items in lst_b
print(new_list)
print(temp)
```

**Output from code above:**

```
['an', 'example of', 'an simple']
["It's", 'English', 'sentence.']
```

**Desired Output:**

```
['It\'s an', 'example of', 'an English simple sentence.']
```

Comment: Just a thought, I also had the idea of finding the length of each string in lst_a [3, 2, 4], and producing a lst_length field that would calculate a new length of each sting based on the rules above. From there, I was thinking maybe I could give the lst_length properties to lst_b.

Comment: Hi @teddygraham, looks like you are expanding on an earlier solution. This is so cool. A few questions before we get started. Are you expecting contractions to be fixed before the comparison happens?

Comment: Hey @JoeFerndz, you can actually take credit for a lot of the progress! So what I'm trying to accomplish is: I'm taking text from a speech to text service, and transcribing audio to convert to subtitles for the corresponding video. I'm using the Azure speech to text SDK. How the tool is designed the output is a JSON file with 3 values (Offset, Duration, and Word). There is also an output `DisplayText` which has all of the formatted text (capitalization, spellings, and punctuation). What I want to do, is take the `DisplayText` and swap it with the formatted `word` values.

Comment: In both files I'm working with, I will have the order that the words appear. But I assume that other contractions, aside from it's, weren't, etc, will exist. For example, `google dot com` is how the text would be formatted in the JSON file, and `google.com` is how it would be formatted in the `DisplayText`.

Comment: so what i am assuming from your code is `lst_a` is `DisplayText` and `lst_b` is `word` values. Let me try to make this much easier for you. I already have a code I was working with. I can expand that and send you an updated version. Maybe that will help you.

Comment: Actually, it's the other way around `lst_a` is `word` and `lst_b` is `DisplayText`. That's because I can get the timestamp of when a particular `word` is said, so I can convert it to a string. Regardless, that sounds great to me, I'm not stuck on a particular method!

Comment: I had also considered looking into some Python NLP libraries like spaCY.

Comment: Also, I should say thank you again for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to consider from your original assumption:

- If a words appears both in `lst_a` and `lst_b`, I want to include it in `new_lst`.
- If a word appears in `lst_b` and does not appear in `lst_a`, I want it included it in `new_lst`.
- If a word appears in `lst_a` and not in `lst_b`, I do not want it included in in `new_lst`.

Let's take an example of `lst_a` and `lst_b`:

`lst_a = ['this is', 'a boy', 'from this town']`

`lst_b = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'big', 'boy', 'from', 'town']`

Based on the above three conditions, you can see that all items in `lst_b` will be in `new_list`. There is no option which an item from `lst_b` can get missed out from `new_lst`. Do you agree?

On the other hand, if an item from `lst_a` is not in `lst_b`, then it will show up in `temp`.

In the above example, the value `this` is part of lst_b[0] but I am assuming that you want the word `this` from `lst[3]` to show up in `temp`.

`new_lst = ['this is', 'a big boy', 'from town']`

`temp = ['this']`

With that said, the below code works in both conditions. The only assumption is that there is only one word at any given time missing from either `lst_a` or `lst_b`.

### **Solution for the post**

```
import re

#Original List of words - this will be word

lst_a = ['it is an', 'example of', 'a english simple sentence', 'if time permits', 'i will learn','this weekend', 'but do not', 'count on me']

#This is the DisplayText list to be compared against. Master List

lst_b = ['It\'s', 'an', 'example', 'of', 'an', 'English', 'perfect', 'simple', 'sentence.', 'If', 'time', 'permits,','I\'ll', 'learn','this','weekend', 'but', 'don\'t','count', 'on', 'me']

#This is lookup list to replace Contractions 

ch = {'it is':'it\'s','i will':'i\'ll','do not':'don\'t'}

#let's first process lst_a and prepare the modified lst_a list for comparison
#we will use lst_ac to manipulate the original list (lst_a)

def a_lst_setup (lst_ac):

    #replace possible contractions as lst_b is a list with contractions

    for k,v in ch.items():
        lst_ac = [a.replace(k,v) for a in lst_ac]

    #create final list to compare against lst_b but keep original list pattern

    lst_a_temp = [j for i in lst_ac for j in [i.split(' ')]]

    return lst_a_temp

def b_lst_setup (lst_bc):

    #create a simple list of all lst_b values with no punctiations or capitalization

    lst_b_temp = [re.sub('[,.;:]','',i).lower() for i in lst_bc]

    return lst_b_temp

#let's first setup lst_a so it includes contractions
#lst_a will still be setup as a list within a list
#Each list is a phrase broken down into single words so we can compare against lst_b

lst_a_compare = a_lst_setup(lst_a)

#let's remove all punctuations and capitalizations from lst_b
lst_b_compare = b_lst_setup(lst_b)

#now both lst_a and lst_b are ready to be compared at same level.

new_lst = []
temp = []

lb = 0

for i in lst_a_compare: #iterate thru each item in final list

    t = '' #temporary string to append to final list

    for j in i: #for each set of words from lst_a, check if they are in lst_b

        #if word from lst_a is in lst_b, then create the final phrase to match lst_a
        #if word from lst_a not in lst_b, then one of two things
        #lst_a has a word that's not in lst_b  OR
        #lst_b has a word that's not in lst_a
        #so first check if lst_a word is in lst_b (next word)
        #if found, then append to text phrase
        #if not found, then write to temp

        #this logic may need further improvement as my assumption is
        #only one word is missing at any given time from lst_a or lst_b

        if j.lower() == lst_b_compare[lb]:
            if t == '': t = lst_b[lb]
            else: t = ' '.join([t,lst_b[lb]])
            lb +=1 #increment lst_b counter only if word in lst_b
        elif j.lower() == lst_b_compare[lb+1]:
            if t == '': t = lst_b[lb] + ' ' + lst_b[lb+1]
            else: t = ' '.join([t,lst_b[lb],lst_b[lb+1]])
            lb +=2
        else:
            temp.append(j)

    #write the newly created phrase to final list

    new_lst.append(t)

print ('lst_a     : ', lst_a,   '\n')
print ('lst_b     : ', lst_b,   '\n')
print ('lst_final : ', new_lst, '\n')
print ('temp      : ', temp)
```

**Output for this shows as:**

```
lst_a     :  ['it is an', 'example of', 'a english simple sentence', 'if time permits', 'i will learn', 'this weekend', 'but do not', 'count on me'] 

lst_b     :  ["It's", 'an', 'example', 'of', 'an', 'English', 'perfect', 'simple', 'sentence.', 'If', 'time', 'permits,', "I'll", 'learn', 'this', 'weekend', 'but', "don't", 'count', 'on', 'me'] 

lst_final :  ["It's an", 'example of', 'an English perfect simple sentence.', 'If time permits,', "I'll learn", 'this weekend', "but don't", 'count on me'] 

temp      :  ['a']
```

Here the word `a` in `lst_a` is extra and not part of `lst_b`. So it was written into temp.

Similarly, the word `perfect` was not part of `lst_a` but existed in `lst_b`. So I just added it in the same position as it should appear in `lst_b`.

Hopefully that's what you were looking for in your response.

This one took me a while to figure out as the logic is still flakey. I may need some more time to come up with a better logic to address variations of mismatches.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you for posting this! I know it was a lot to figure out!

Comment: great. happy to know that this helped. There is still room for improvement on this. I will keep thinking about this and if I come up with something, i will post here.